# payto method electrum wallet jsonRPC PHP

Tags: php, bitcoin, json-rpc

Yo!

I just started a script with php and electrum wallet using jsonRPC.

Call as getaddressbalance() work, but what's about payto? I tried :
$bitcoin->payto("adresse","ammount"); but its not looking to work.

Any ideas? addrequest()?

Answer (score -1):

The `payto` command will return you an unsigned transaction in hex. You will then need to `broadcast` that transaction to the network.